# Vibrator in android

Tags: android

How to create Vibrator object and call vibrate function? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html doesn't give much information regarding how to create the object ( no public constructors )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
Vibrator bzzz = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#VIBRATOR_SERVICE).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the object then call the function object.vibrate whith vibration period in milliseconds

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
// To vibrate for 1 second
v.vibrate(1000);
```