# Vibrator on Android

Tags: java, android

I read a lot about this problem on Stackoverflow but not of the Helps her works at my problem.

In my Source Code I have this.

```
vibretor  = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibretor.vibrate(600);
```

and in the AndroidManifeste.xml I have the Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

this is all right I think because i looked it up at
http://developer.android.com

but it does not worke at all :(
So have someone of you a idea how I can get it working?

My testing Devices are: Eee Pad Transformer, Samsung Galaxy S2 and Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3108154/517561, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4430781/517561

Comment: did u try some bigger values like 5000 instead of 600, bcoz 600 might be milliseconds which might be minor.

Comment: Try this `Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); vib.vibrate(600);`

Comment: @AndroSelva Value is not a problem because I have used the same code with a value of 50 and still its felt.

Comment: Also check if the device `hasVibrator ()`

Comment: I tryed it with bigger values like 1000 but it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.

The problem was that, under android 4.0, the vibration settings must be

*Vibration on touch*

and not

*Ringtone*
or
*Notification*

and then it work with my code.

```
vibretor  = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibretor.vibrate(600);
```

Comment: thanks! On my Note3, it is Device>Sound>Vibration Intensity>Notification

Answer (score 1):

```
public void vibrate(int duration)
              {
   Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
   v.vibrate(duration);    
              }
vibrate(10000);
```

Comment: Why you want to get the parameter as `String` and then convert it to `int`? Why don't you get it as a `int` on first hand?

Comment: I have used this in my Application. In that i have get the vibration duration from textbox, so that i have passed as string. Now check the edited code.